# change output pane language

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have postgresql and using pg admin.
the problem is my system and everything is in English except errors and messages in output pane.
I have already set the user language to English but still the messages are in German!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute the following SQL statement:

```
SET lc_messages="C";
```

That will change the messages you get and also the messages in the log file.

You can only set this parameter when you are a superuser, but you can create a superuser-owned function with `SECURITY DEFINER` and grant `EXECUTE` on it to a normal user:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_english() RETURNS void
   LANGUAGE sql SECURITY DEFINER AS
   'SET lc_messages="C"';

REVOKE EXECUTE ON FUNCTION set_english() FROM PUBLIC;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION set_english() TO laurenz;
```

Then user `laurenz` can call the function to change the setting.

Comment: Are sure about `"C"`? Shouldn't that be `lc_messages='English'`?

Comment: As far as message language are concerned, that is the same thing.

Comment: may I ask another question? I checked database properties, and the collation and character type are German, since I live in Switzerland. Should I change it, since all my data is English? and I do text search. does it have any affect on the result!

Comment: @Raha1986: if this answered your question, accept the answer. Then ask a **new** question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name...I did :)